# PDO variable not working in query but static value works

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo

so my situation is something like this , i'm trying to fetch user details based on `id` that isset is getting, but some how the `variable that contains the $_GET value doesn't work` in query but when i put an static value to pdo query then it works and show the result. i have checked by doing `var_dump` of variable `$user` before query and it shows the correct value but not working in query. Below is the code i'm working with:

```
public function profile_view($user_id = null) {
            $user = $user_id;
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT memberID,username,email,profile_pic,active FROM members WHERE memberID = :user_id AND active="YES"');
            $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$user));
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $user_det = (object) array('username'=> $row['username'],'email'=>$row['email'],'profile_pic'=>$row['profile_pic'],'id'=> $row['memberID'],'active'=>$row['active']);

            return $user_det;
            }


    }
```

this is how function is being called (profile_view function is child of User class so $user is class User) :

```
 $view_profile = $user->profile_view($_GET['u']);
```

the above code returns null but when i put static value : `5` at the place of `$user` in `$stmt->execute` it returns the whole user's details which is what i need , but its not working with variable which is confusing me a lot.

Comment: So have you var_dumped your `_GET` value?

Comment: Are you sure you checked the value inside the method?

Comment: Please post how the function is called, enable error reporting and post the errors (if you still need help after the thrown error has told you the problem)

Comment: i'm 100% sure that when i do var_dump on $user variable it shows correct value. but don't know why it doesn't work in query.

Comment: @michael error reporting is on there are no errors at all , it only shows null result. and i'm updating my question with how function is being called.

Answer (score 0):

You correct php code. SQL query false (possibly). I do not know you SQL table.

Example php code manual. This link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
?>
```

You SQL code edit and test code.

Comment: to me my whole code seems okay , but not getting whats the problem with $user variable and why static value works as i have also done var_dump of $user inside function and it shows me an correct value of $_GET.

Answer (score -3):

When you call the function, you're setting `$user_id` to null, no matter what get passed through it, rather than taking the value of `$user_id`. Try this:

```
$user_id = 5; //Set this to whatever int you want whether it be via POST or GET
public function profile_view($user_id) { //Note that I don't set $user_id equal to anything
    //The rest of the code remains the same
    $user = $user_id;
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT memberID,username,email,profile_pic,active FROM members WHERE memberID = :user_id AND active="YES"');
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$user));
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $user_det = (object) array('username'=> $row['username'],'email'=>$row['email'],'profile_pic'=>$row['profile_pic'],'id'=> $row['memberID'],'active'=>$row['active']);
        return $user_det;
        }
}
```

Comment: `$user_id = null` is defining default value when no value explicitly passed in function call.

Comment: like in question i have mentioned : i have done `var_dump` of `$user` inside function and it shows me the right value of what `$_GET` is getting . there is nuthing to do with null.